# Error:- Method 'range' of object '_global' failed while running 2 functions together

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have made 2 functions "WrongEntries" & "Duplicates". When I run it individually it runs perfectly. But when I run it one after the other it reflects **Method 'range' of object '_global' failed**.

I am not sure is it because of the objects still in the memory of the previous run function but i did use different objects & variable in both functions still same error was there. Also tried putting objects as nothing.

Stange part is if I shuffle their run-first one always runs perfectly doesn't matter which one it is.

```
Function WrongEntries()
Dim dbs As Database Dim lRow As Long Dim lCol As Long Dim rg As Range

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rgQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("5G High Cycle Times")
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application", "")
excelApp.Visible = True
Set targetWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("\5G Wrong             
Entries_Blank.xlsx")
targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Cycle Times >5 
weeks").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rgQuery
targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Cycle Times >5 weeks").Activate

lRow = Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
excelApp.Quit
Set excelApp = Nothing
End Function
```

''' Problems is when I run second one together with first'''

```
Function Duplicates()

Dim dbs As Database Dim lastRw As Long Dim lastCl As Long Dim rnge As 
Range Dim wks As Worksheet
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application", "")
excelApp.Visible = True
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rdQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset("5G Duplicates Check")
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application", "")
excelApp.Visible = True
Set targetWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("\5G Duplicates_Blank.xlsx")
Set wks = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Duplicates")
targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Duplicates").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset 
rdQuery
```

---

### *Here the error is reflecting while calculating last row count*

```
lastRw = wks.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCl = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You close the application:

```
excelApp.Quit
Set excelApp = Nothing
```

leaving the workbook and all objects orphaned. So:

```
targetWorkbook.Close
Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
excelApp.Quit
Set excelApp = Nothing
```

Further: Always use specific objects. Not

```
Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

but:

```
Set range = SomeWorksheet.Range ...
set cell = SomeWorksheet.Cells ...
```

and terminate these as the first:

```
Set cell = Nothing
Set range = Nothing
Set wks = nothing
targetWorkbook.Close
Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
excelApp.Quit
Set excelApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav for the comments, it surely help me to find the real issue.I used 
"lastRw = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Duplicates").Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row"
in place of the error code and it's working fine now. Anyways i tried your way as well by closing workbook and putting objects of previous function to nothing, but issue was still coming up.

Comment: I don't know even after activating the workbook it won't work without using complete "targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Duplicates")" before using Range keyword.

Comment: Problem may be that you use `.End(xlUp)` and similar, which are UI operations. Learn the programmatic way to determine cell ranges, and you won't have to _activate_ worksheets. Also, it will operate much faster.